# How do I count values in a column based on unique values in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Just wondering if you can help a novice out with the following issue.

```
  ID #   | Yes/No   
  366    | Yes       
  377    | Yes     
  377    | Yes        
  388    | Yes
```

I wish to count the `Yes`s in column 2, but I only want to count them based on a unique ID (i.e. I only want to count 377's `Yes` single time; therefore, the final count should be 3).

Can you please show me how I go about creating that formula?

Comment: You're looking for [Pivot tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Comment: Are you wanting to keep all your duplicates? If not, I'd just use **data > remove duplicates** from the ribbon.

Comment: Yes, I wish to keep the duplicates on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$5 = "Yes",1/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,$A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5,"Yes"))))
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]